# Special characters in batch

Tags: batch-file, symbols

I want to use these special chacarters: █ ▄ ▌ ▐ ▀ (alt+219 to alt+223), ♥ (alt+3), • (alt 7), ► ◄ (alt+16/17), ▲ ▼ (alt+30/31) and Φ (alt+232) in a batch file. If I write them in notepad (using unicode) the batch file will show me some letters. I know the letter codes for:

> Notepad: ┌┬┐ ├┼┤ └┴┘ ─ │
>
> cmd.exe: ÚÂ¿ ÃÅ´ ÀÁÙ Ä ³
>
> Notepad: ╔╦╗ ╠╬╣ ╚╩╝ ═ ║
>
> cmd.exe: ÉË» ÌÎ¹ ÈÊ¼ Í º

but i also need them for the symbols above. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: You can easily generate this data yourself with `echo  █ ▄ ▌ ▐ ▀ >squares.txt` and then see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it like this:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 >NUL
set symbols=█ ▄ ▌ ▐ ▀ ╔╦╗ ╠╬╣ ╚╩╝ ═ ║ ┌┬┐ ├┼┤ └┴┘ ─ │ ♥ • ► ◄ ▲ ▼ Φ
echo %symbols%
title %symbols%
echo/
pause
```

The important bit here is `chcp 65001 >NUL`

`chcp 65001` f**orces UTF-8** encoding for that particular batch file.
You can change the registry to have this as a default but this is a localised way to do so. That thread can be [found here](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8).

`>NUL` this **nullifies** the output of above